# Trying to change the text of an NSString. Does Not Work

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I am trying to make a string in another view equal Yes.
I did this:

```
reset = @"Yes";
NSLog(@"resetString is %@", reset);
```

**The NSLog above equals Yes.**

And in my second view, it is supposed to check if it equals yes and do something.

```
ScoreViewController *svc = [[ScoreViewController alloc] init];
    if ([svc.reset isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
    {
        selectedQuestion.questionCompleteOrNot = @"No";
        NSLog(@"resetString is %@", svc.reset);
    }
    else
    {
        selectedQuestion.questionCompleteOrNot = @"Yes";
        NSLog(@"resetString is %@", svc.reset);
    }
```

The two NSLogs above equal Null, when they should equal Yes, so it does something to the selectedQuestion.questionCompleteOrNot property.

Anyone know?

Comment: You have not posted enough information to answer this question. Is reset a declared property of your svc object, and if so how did you declare it?

Comment: I declared it like this: @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *reset;

Answer (score 1):

This creates a new instance of your `ScoreViewController` class:

```
 ScoreViewController *svc = [[ScoreViewController alloc] init];
```

My guess, you're not actually setting a default value for your property `reset`. Hence, you likely need to do something like this within your `ScoreViewController`'s `init:` method:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _reset = @"Yes";
       // set other default values here...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Also, if you need to brush up on the basics of iOS development, I highly recommend Ray Wenderlich's site, which has lots of high quality tutorials:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/

Good luck!

**Edit**

By the way, if `ScoreViewController` is actually a subclass of `UIViewController`, you may be using the wrong init method... instead, you should likely be using `-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` method... here's a link to the `UIViewController` documentation, which should help as well:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I get an error: control reaches end of non-void function

Comment: Sorry, `init:` should actually return `self`... see edited method in answer. Please also note that this is just an example `init:` method. You should probably be using `initWithNibName:bundle:` method if this is a `UIViewController` subclass...

Answer (score 0):

Check if you assign the value in a different block of code.
(a block of code = starts and ends with {} )
If you instantiate a variable or assign value in a different block, it won't work.